# I want to control robot from internet. Do i need Rosbridge or is there any other way?

Tags: ros, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using platform ubantu on PC and having ROS indigo on my robot. I want to control my robot from remote location using internet. So do i need rosbridge or can i do it with any other way?? Thanks in advance !!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237992/i-want-to-control-robot-from-internet.-do-i-need-rosbridge-or-is-there-any-other-way??/) by [swati shirke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27205/swati-shirke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, adding '*from [the] internet*' to your question doesn't really add much to [the already asked question](http://answers.ros.org/question/237348/do-i-need-to-use-rosbridge-for-controlling-my-robot-from-my-pc/?answer=237356#post-id-237356).

If, by '*from [the] internet*', you mean '*on a computer connected to the internet*', networking is already baked into ROS, so rosbridge is not necessary. You need to learn about the ROS_MASTER_URI and possibly the ROS_IP environment variables.

If, on the other hand, you mean '*from within a web browser*', then yes, [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite)  can serve as a tool to help you do that. You can look at the list of [experimental ROS client libraries](http://wiki.ros.org/Client%20Libraries#Experimental_client_libraries); specifically, you'd likely be interested in [rosnodejs](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnodejs). Even more specifically, you should look into [robot web tools](http://robotwebtools.org/), and even more specifically than that, at the *Widgets* section on the [Tools](http://robotwebtools.org/tools.html) page.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swati shirke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27205/swati-shirke/) on 2016-07-17**:
Thank you very much!!